# How to reduce called paramets in methods?

Tags: python, django

I have a class and in that class I have a method that calls multiple methods in it.

But the problem I am facing now is that when the method with the multiple methods in it duplicate parameter has.

And so when I am calling the method with the multiple methods in it, it returns a empty list:[].

So this is the method with the multiple methods in it:

```
 def show_extracted_data_from_file(self,  file_name):
        self.extractingText.extract_text_from_image(file_name)
        total_fruit = self.filter_verdi_total_number_fruit()
        fruit_name = self.filter_verdi_fruit_name()
        fruit_total_cost = self.filter_verdi_total_fruit_cost(file_name)

        return "\n".join("{} \t {} \t {}".format(a, b, c) for a, b, c in zip(total_fruit, fruit_name, fruit_total_cost))
```

and this is the method: filter_verdi_total_fruit_cost:

```
   def filter_verdi_total_fruit_cost(self, file_name):
        locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, locale='Dutch')
        self.extractingText.extract_text_from_image(file_name)
        return [
            locale.atof(items[-1]) for items in (
                token.split() for token in file_name.split('\n')
            ) if len(items) > 2 and items[1] in self.extractingText.list_fruit
        ]
```

this method returns the following data:

```
[123.2, 2772.0, 46.2, 577.5, 69.3, 3488.16, 137.5, 500.0, 1000.0, 2000.0, 1000.0, 381.25]
```

You see that I am calling two times file_name.

and so when I calling the method show_extracted_data_from_file in the views.py:

```
if uploadfile.image.path.endswith('.pdf'):
                    content = filter_text.show_extracted_data_from_file(uploadfile.image.path)
                    print(content)
```

it produces a empty list: []

Question: how can I reduce the parameter file_name so that it will return the correct results?

this are my two other methods that I am calling in the combined method:

```
  def filter_verdi_total_number_fruit(self):
        regex = r"(\d*(?:\.\d+)*)\s*\W+(?:" + '|'.join(re.escape(word)
                                                       for word in self.extractingText.list_fruit) + ')'
        return re.findall(regex, self.extractingText.text_factuur_verdi[0])

    def filter_verdi_fruit_name(self):
        regex = r"(?:\d*(?:\.\d+)*)\s*\W+(" + '|'.join(re.escape(word)
                                                       for word in self.extractingText.list_fruit) + ')'
        return re.findall(regex, self.extractingText.text_factuur_verdi[0])
```

So this is the other class:

```
class ExtractingTextFromFile:

    def extract_text_from_image(self, filename):

        self.text_factuur_verdi = []
        pdf_file = wi(filename=filename, resolution=300)
        all_images = pdf_file.convert('jpeg')

        for image in all_images.sequence:
            image = wi(image=image)
            image = image.make_blob('jpeg')
            image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image))

            text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng')
            self.text_factuur_verdi.append(text)

        return self.text_factuur_verdi

    def __init__(self):
        # class variables:
     
        self.tex_factuur_verdi = []
        self.list_fruit = ['Appels', 'Ananas', 'Peen Waspeen',
                           'Tomaten Cherry', 'Sinaasappels',
                           'Watermeloenen', 'Rettich', 'Peren', 'Peen',
                           'Mandarijnen', 'Meloenen', 'Grapefruit', 'Rettich']
```

Comment: Are you saying how can you change `self.extractingText.extract_text_from_image(file_name)` so that you are working on the same file?

Comment: @AndrewRyan. I am uploading a file and then from the uploaded file it extracts some data from that file. The method for extracting the data is: extract_text_from_image. So of course that method has to be called just once. But now  it calls it multiple times.

Comment: So why not just remove it from `filter_verdi_total_fruit_cost()` (and saving that output as a class variable)? do you use that function elsewhere or are there functions that use `filter_verdi_total_fruit_cost()` as a part of their output?

Comment: @AndrewRyan. I am not using the function  filter_verdi_total_fruit_cos elswhere

Comment: So then you can either: remove `self.extractingText.extract_text_from_image(file_name)` from inside filter_verdi_total_fruit_cost() having show_extracted_data_from_file() create the text and use that output. OR you could leave them both in but instead add a guardclause / check to self.extractingText.extract_text_from_image(file_name) to check if you have created an output with `file_name` before and skip it if it has.

Comment: @AndrewRyan  Oke, but what I am doing with file_name in the method filter_verdi_total_fruit_cost()?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249210/discussion-between-mightycode-newton-and-andrew-ryan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@AndrewRyan has the right idea.

I presume calling  `extract_text_from_image` just adds the attribute `list_fruit`
Two routes you can go, from what you are commenting you'll probably just go with #1.. but I gave #2 as another option in case you'd ever want to call `filter_verdi_total_fruit_cost` by itself.

##### Path 1, Just remove it.

> **Note:** `filter_verdi_total_fruit_cost` is **only** called from `show_extracted_data_from_file`.

```py
def show_extracted_data_from_file(self,  file_name):

    # extract text
    #  Note: stores data in `self.extractingText.list_fruit`
    self.extractingText.extract_text_from_image(file_name)

    total_fruit = self.filter_verdi_total_number_fruit()
    fruit_name = self.filter_verdi_fruit_name()
    fruit_total_cost = self.filter_verdi_total_fruit_cost()

    return "\n".join("{} \t {} \t {}".format(a, b, c) for a, b, c in zip(total_fruit, fruit_name, fruit_total_cost))

def filter_verdi_total_fruit_cost(self):
    # Note: `self.extractingText.list_fruit` should be already defined

    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, locale='Dutch')
    return [
        locale.atof(items[-1]) for items in (
            token.split() for token in file_name.split('\n')
        ) if len(items) > 2 and items[1] in self.extractingText.list_fruit
    ]
```

##### Path 2, Check if it's already extracted- if not, extract; if so, continue

> **Note:** if you wanted to *just* call `filter_verdi_total_fruit_cost`

```py
def show_extracted_data_from_file(self,  file_name):

    # extract text
    #  Note: stores data in `self.extractingText.list_fruit`
    self.extractingText.extract_text_from_image(file_name)

    total_fruit = self.filter_verdi_total_number_fruit()
    fruit_name = self.filter_verdi_fruit_name()
    fruit_total_cost = self.filter_verdi_total_fruit_cost(file_name)

    return "\n".join("{} \t {} \t {}".format(a, b, c) for a, b, c in zip(total_fruit, fruit_name, fruit_total_cost))

def filter_verdi_total_fruit_cost(self, file_name):
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, locale='Dutch')

    if not hasattr(self, 'list_fruit'):
        # file hasn't been extracted yet.. extract it
        #  Note: stores data in `self.extractingText.list_fruit`
        self.extractingText.extract_text_from_image(file_name)

    return [
        locale.atof(items[-1]) for items in (
            token.split() for token in file_name.split('\n')
        ) if len(items) > 2 and items[1] in self.extractingText.list_fruit
    ]
```

Comment: #Nealium   Yes, Oke. But now file_name is undefined in the method filter_verdi_total_fruit_cost(). And of course I can just pas file_name as a paramer in the method. But then it producs an empty list: []

Comment: @mightycodeNewton ahhhhhh!!- yes, cause of the `.split` call... just do **#2**

Comment: #Nealium. Even when I choose option two it returns empty: []

Comment: @mightycodeNewton Can you edit your original answer and add an example of a `file_name` and what `self.extractingText.list_fruit` is?- possibly just put a `print` for each right above your return in `filter_verdi_total_fruit_cost`

Comment: #Nealium  I updated the post

Comment: self.extractingText.text_factuur_verdi[0] this is also called two times because I have that in two almost identical methods

Comment: @mightycodeNewton well hell, you could just throw both in an attribute lol. I think we’re just on preferences now